# How to beat the dual in Apocalypseafterparty by Wherwin in Geometry Dash?

Tags: geometry-dash, mobile

Note: while I already have been able to get past part of the dual, I am still having trouble with those parts in terms of consistency.

So I have been working on beating my
first insane demon as a jump from Nine Circles.

I decided to beat Apocalypseafterparty by Wherwin which I thought would be a good choice as it would also be my third 2-player demon (the other 2 being Arre Robot and Arre Toro) and have currently gotten 38% on it.

However, I decided to do some practice starting at 40%, where the drop happens.

This is sadly where I am having trouble because of how difficult the dual section is.

While I am not having trouble with the first part (UFO/Cube -> Wave/Cube (although I need to practice spamming with my left hand more)) the next part is giving me trouble.

This is a Cube/Cube part where you need to pick up keys that are assigned to the two “players” when you start the dual.

The path is as follows

```
First set of keys: Jump with P1 (by default is left hand/space)

Second set of keys: Jump with both players (left hand & right hand/space and mouse)

Third set of keys: Jump with both players

Fourth set of keys: jump on the pink orb with both players
```

Note: On my run where I got 52.03%, I accidentally didn’t notice the pink orb and accidentally ended up failing.

However, I don’t know what to do from here, so my question is:

How do I beat the dual in Apocalypseafterparty by Wherwin?

[<kbd>Video of runs</kbd>](https://youtu.be/Mj3PFNZuip0?si=gCtGlixSsXp1qS7d)